# Clip / trim / crop a tikz graphic after creation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an image

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[trim=400 450 500 450, clip,width=0.9\textwidth]{../Bilder/Explanations/early-abandoning.png}};
%     [trim=left bottom right top, clip]
    \draw (3,2) -- ++(70:3cm) -- ++(-50:1cm) -- ++(20:1cm) -- ++(0:1cm);
    \draw (3,2) -- ++(70:3cm) -- ++(-50:1cm) -- ++(20:1cm) -- ++(0:1cm);
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

that I would like to crop. If I clip it further in `\includegraphics`, the lines won't fit anymore. Thus, I would like to crop the image further after placing all the lines etc. How can I do this?

### To clarify:

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

This is what I get if I only change the trim in `\includegraphics`:

[image]

Comment: Would you mind adding a picture? I have a hard time understanding what you want.

Comment: @marmot: Done in the question.

Comment: Well, it looks like you are clipping the wrong region. Notice that you can also clip within Ti*k*Z.

Comment: @marmot: Maybe you can show me the code how, because I don't know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment. I downloaded your picture, so most likely things got rescaled. And this snippet clips some part of the picture.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (sw) at (0,0);
\coordinate (ne) at (8,8);
\begin{scope}
    \clip  (sw) rectangle (ne); % clip some region
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (-4,-4)  %<-move the image center
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{early-abandoning.png}};
\end{scope} 
%     [trim=left bottom right top, clip]
    \draw (3,2) -- ++(70:3cm) -- ++(-50:1cm) -- ++(20:1cm) -- ++(0:1cm);
    \draw (3,2) -- ++(70:3cm) -- ++(-50:1cm) -- ++(20:1cm) -- ++(0:1cm);
    \begin{scope}[x={8cm},y={8cm}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit by Make42:**

Here the solution that clips the entire tikzpicture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (sw) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (ne) at (6,6);
    \begin{scope}
        \clip  (sw) rectangle (ne); % clip some region
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[trim=450 450 500 450, clip,width=0.9\textwidth]{../Bilder/Explanations/early-abandoning.png}};
    %     [trim=left bottom right top, clip]
        \draw (3,2) -- ++(70:3cm) -- ++(-50:1cm) -- ++(20:1cm) -- ++(0:1cm);
        \draw (3,2) -- ++(70:3cm) -- ++(-50:1cm) -- ++(20:1cm) -- ++(0:1cm);
        \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
            \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
            \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Aren't you just clipping the image that was included with includegraphics? I want to clip the entire tikzpicture.

Comment: I added the solution that I actually wanted. If you accept the edit, I will accept the answer.

Comment: @Make42 I see. I was suspecting that, but was not sure why you are adding the axes later. Some rejected the edit because they thought (I think) that my code did not clip at all, which is understandable. I hope they're fine with me approving the edit.

Comment: The axis are only for orientation - I will remove them later anyway.